# Main and Sub panel wiring mixture in a single switch box

Tags: electrical

When you have circuits from a main and sub-panel in the same box, do you need to keep the grounds and neutral separate or can you connect them together?  My gut says they have to be separate but I can't find a specific code section for that question.

Comment: Neutrals are always kept separate on a per-cable basis, not even per-circuit.  If the hot wires from cable X and Y interact in this box (e.g. by going to the same switch or light), then their neutrals connect.  Otherwise they do not. NEC 300.3, currents must be equal/opposite in each cable or conduit.  You are required to mark wires/cables to indicate the differences; gray is an allowed neutral color so gray tape will suffice.

Comment: If it's not already, it seems like a _very good idea_ to ensure that the box is labeled to indicate that power is not only coming from 2 circuits, but that the circuits are in two different panels. Seems like it'd save someone (possibly future you) a bunch of trouble next time around in identifying why something there is still hot.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Ground is ground is ground; you can always connect them together.</s> Edit: actually, thinking further, always interconnect grounds **except** between different panels. The problem with mixing grounds between panels in case of a failure, the resulting ground connection may be too small. See more below.

Neutral is another story. Even without a sub panel, never interconnect neutrals from different circuits. Neutrals are not protected so if you end up with different circuit’s neutrals connected, you could end up overloading one. Also, if you have a GFCI in the line, it will trip with mixed neutrals.

Edit, now that I have more time, more on mixing neutrals.

Let's say that you mix neutrals on two 20 amp circuits. You then fully load both circuits. Each hot is carrying 20 amps and the neutrals together are returning 40 amps. Hopefully it's split evenly, 20 amps per neutral.

But now lets say that something happened to one of the neutrals. Maybe there's just a bit of extra resistance in one of the junctions or worse, someone drove a nail right through the neutral (they didn't notice it because nothing stopped working). Now one neutral is carrying less current and the other one more (more than its rated 20 amps!). Worse case, one 20 amp wire is carrying 40 amps! The circuit breakers aren't tripping; the hots are still only carrying 20 amps each and the neutrals aren't monitored. Pretty soon, the neutral wire is red hot and causing a fire in your walls!

Now let's take your case of a neutral wire from your main panel and a neutral wire from a (say, 100 amp) sub panel and they are interconnected. Now lets say that something happens to the 100 amp neutral from the sub back to the main. Now, you have the entire sub panel's neutral current running back through your 20 amp neutral wires! That's a house fire for sure!

Edit: Connecting grounds between the main and sub panel could cause the same problem. If the 100 amp ground back from the sub panel fails, now the sub panel to main panel ground is via the interconnected 20 amp grounds. If there ends up a (not-quite) full short hot to ground in the sub panel, the ground current will return via the 20 amp grounds. The 100 amp breaker may not trip before the ground wires burn up. (If the grounds are via metal conduit, the grounds will interconnect anyway but there's plenty of current carrying capacity so no problem.)

GFCIs don't work by monitoring ground current. They actually work by comparing the hot and neutral current. If they differ by more than a few milliamps, the GFCI assumes that the missing current is flowing to ground (maybe though a person) and trips. This is why mixing neutrals will trip upstream GFCIs. Say you have two 20 amp circuits on GFCI breakers with the neutrals interconnected. You turn on a 10 amp load on one of them. Breaker one sees 10 amps hot but only around 5 amps neutral and trips. Breaker two sees 0 amps hot but around 5 amps neutral and also trips.

Comment: I'm not sure the grounds can be co-mingled if from different panels (different circuits isn't a problem). NEC 250.130(C)(4) specifies for retro-fit grounds that you must tie back to a circuit on the same panel - I don't know why they would prohibit retro-fit grounds from another panel if co-mingling grounds from different panels was allowed anyway.

Comment: @kg333 Think about it further, I can see a problem. It's kind of the same with neutrals between panels. If the 100 amp ground fails, the ground back from the sub to the main is now running over the 20 amp ground wires. If there is a (not quite) full short, the 100 amp breaker may not trip before the ground wire burns up. On the other hand, if you're using metal conduit as ground, it'll all be interconnected anyway.

Comment: @kg333 -- EGCs run as part of original wiring are permitted to be commingled freely (otherwise, conduit systems would need to jump thru all sorts of hoops)